# Language/Framework suggestions for web application

Tags: web-applications, frameworks

I'm hoping to find suggestions for language for a cross-platform/cross-browser update of our application. JavaScript would work for what we're doing, but debugging in JavaScript is too painful to be a viable option. Requirements are listed below:

Application should be usable online as well as offline.
Preferably an active developer community.
Available GUI libraries to avoid having to reinvent the wheel.
Interact with local files on the disk as well as a web service when online

Other options we've considered have been Dart, and Python using Django (although I'm not totally certain this would be able to do everything we need). Our initial consideration was a C# Silverlight app, but because of the questionable future of Silverlight we're seeking another option with similar functionality.

If I've been too vague I'll try to give more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to choose from, and you have the luxury of choosing the language you are most comfortable with.  Most if not all frameworks should work offline.  Some of my recommendations would be:

Java:
  Vaadin,
  Google Web toolkit,
  Spring

Python:
  web2py,
  Django,
  Google app engine

Ruby:
  Ruby on rails

Here is a wiki link for a comparison of different frameworks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks